# Convert Date Stored as VARCHAR into INT to compare to Date Stored as INT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014. My request I believe is rather simple. I have one table containing a field holding a date value that is stored as `VARCHAR`, and another table containing a field holding a date value that is stored as `INT`.

The date value in the `VARCHAR` field is stored like this: **2015M01**
The data value in the `INT` field is stored like this: **201501**

I need to compare these tables against each other using `EXCEPT`. My thought process was to somehow extract or TRIM the "M" out of the `VARCHAR` value and see if it would let me compare the two. If anyone has a better idea such as using CAST to change the date formats or something feel free to suggest that as well.

I am also concerned that even extracting the "M" out of the `VARCHAR` may still prevent the comparison since one will still remain `VARCHAR` and the other is `INT`. If possible through a T-SQL query to convert on the fly that would be great advice as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you already have the query and are using `EXCEPT`, you can simply change the definition of that one "date" field in the query containing the `VARCHAR` value so that it matches the `INT` format of the other query. For example:

```sql
SELECT Field1, CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(VarcharDateField, 'M', '')) AS [DateField], Field3
FROM   TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT Field1, IntDateField, Field3
FROM   TableB
```

ＨＯＷＥＶＥＲ, while I realize that this might not be feasible, your best option, if you can make this happen, would be to change how the data in the table with the `VARCHAR` field is stored so that it is actually an `INT` in the same format as the table with the data already stored as an `INT`. Then you wouldn't have to worry about situations like this one.

Meaning:

- Add an `INT` field to the table with the `VARCHAR` field.
- Do an `UPDATE` of that table, setting the `INT` field to the string value with the `M` removed.
- Update any INSERT and/or UPDATE stored procedures used by external services (app, ETL, etc) to do that same `M` removal logic on the way in. Then you don't have to change any app code that does INSERTs and UPDATEs. You don't even need to tell anyone you did this.
- Update any "get" / SELECT stored procedures used by external services (app, ETL, etc) to do the opposite logic: convert the `INT` to `VARCHAR` and add the `M` on the way out. Then you don't have to change any app code that gets data from the DB. You don't even need to tell anyone you did this.

This is one of many reasons that having a Stored Procedure API to your DB is quite handy. I suppose an ORM can just be rebuilt, but you still need to recompile, even if all of the code references are automatically updated. But making a datatype change (or even moving a field to a different table, or even replacinga a field with a simple `CASE` statement) "behind the scenes" and masking it so that any code outside of your control doesn't know that a change happened, not nearly as difficult as most people might think. I have done all of these operations (datatype change, move a field to a different table, replace a field with simple logic, etc, etc) and it buys you a lot of time until the app code can be updated. That might be another team who handles that. Maybe their schedule won't allow for making any changes in that area (plus testing) for 3 months. Ok. It will be there waiting for them when they are ready. Any if there are several areas to update, then they can be done one at a time. You can even create new stored procedures to run in parallel for any updated app code to have the proper `INT` datatype as the input parameter. And once all references to the `VARCHAR` value are gone, then delete the original versions of those stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

**[REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)** the string and then **[CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)** to integer

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT intField 
    FROM TableB
   ) as  B
ON CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(A.varcharField, 'M', ''))  = B.intField
```

Comment: Interesting. This looks like it may work although I currently am using an except between two queries. So I have one query with multiple joins and then an except in between. So I am not sure I can use the join as you suggested? Maybe alias out each query? I am basically comparing all data and hoping for nothing to return which means all data matches.

Comment: Yes, just put your query between `()` and use alias or use some CTE to make things more readable

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything in the first table that is not in the second, you might consider something like this:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where cast(replace(t1.varcharfield, 'M', '') as int) = t2.intfield
                 );
```

This should be close enough to `except` for your purposes.

I should add that you might need to include other columns in the `where` statement.  However, the question only mentions one column, so I don't know what those are.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a persisted view on the table with the char column, with a calculated column where the `M` is removed.  Then you could `JOIN` the view to the table containing the `INT` column.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.PersistedView
WITH SCHEMA_BINDING
AS
SELECT ConvertedDateCol = CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(VarcharCol, 'M', ''))
    --, other columns including the PK, etc
FROM dbo.TablewithCharColumn;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_PersistedView
ON dbo.PersistedView(<the PK column>);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.PersistedView pv
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableWithIntColumn ic ON pv.ConvertedDateCol = ic.IntDateCol;
```

If you provide the actual details of both tables, I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

A persisted view with a computed column will perform far better on the `SELECT` statement where you join the two columns compared with doing the `CONVERT` and `REPLACE` every time you run the `SELECT` statement.

However, a persisted view will slightly slow down inserts into the underlying table(s), and will prevent you from making DDL changes to the underlying tables.

If you're looking to not persist the values via a schema-bound view, you could create a non-persisted computed column on the table itself, then create a non-clustered index on that column.  If you are using the computed column in `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses, you may see some benefit.

By way of example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PCT
(
    PCT_ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_PCT
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SomeChar VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , SomeCharToInt AS CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SomeChar, 'M', ''))
);

CREATE INDEX IX_PCT_SomeCharToInt
ON dbo.PCT(SomeCharToInt);

INSERT INTO dbo.PCT(SomeChar)
VALUES ('2015M08');

SELECT SomeCharToInt
FROM dbo.PCT;
```

Results:

[image]